# How to make a Lightning-Icon clickable

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have an input field with a lightning icon (+) that I would like to make clickable:

[image]

```
<label class="slds-form-element__label" for="combobox-id-3">{lookupLabel}</label>  
<div data-key="searchdiv" class="slds-combobox__form-element slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right" role="none">  
<input type="text" onfocusout={onLeave} value={searchKey} onkeyup={handleKeyChange} onchange={handleKeyChange} class="slds-input slds-combobox__input slds-has-focus" id="combobox-id-3" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="listbox-id-2" role="textbox" placeholder="Search..." />  
<span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-search slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right">  
<lightning-icon icon-name="utility:add" size="xx-Small" class="slds-icon slds-icon slds-icon_x-small slds-icon-text-default" aria-hidden="true"></lightning-icon>
</span>  
</div>
```

So far I've tried:

```
<button>
<lightning-icon icon-name="utility:add" size="xx-Small" class="slds-icon slds-icon slds-icon_x-small slds-icon-text-default" aria-hidden="true">
</lightning-icon>
</button>
```

and

```
<div onclick={doSomething}>
<lightning-icon icon-name="utility:add" size="xx-Small" class="slds-icon slds-icon slds-icon_x-small slds-icon-text-default" aria-hidden="true">
</lightning-icon>
</div>
```

Unfortunately the outcome is not what I am looking for. I want to make it an action where the cursor icon would change the same way it changes when hovering over a button and a JS controller method would fire the same way it does for example using a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the input element is over the icon, inspecting the element with the console you could see that the input element has some padding, so clicking there you're clicking on the input element.

No matter which component you use, a `lightning-icon`, a `lightning-button-icon` or a standard `button`, it would be the same.

You just have to move those elements:

```html
<label class="slds-form-element__label" for="combobox-id-3">{lookupLabel}</label>
<div class="slds-is-relative">
    <div data-key="searchdiv" class="slds-combobox__form-element slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right" role="none">  
        <input type="text" onfocusout={onLeave} value={searchKey} onkeyup={handleKeyChange} onchange={handleKeyChange} class="slds-input slds-combobox__input slds-has-focus" id="combobox-id-3" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="listbox-id-2" role="textbox" placeholder="Search..." />   
    </div>
    <span style="right: 0.5rem; top: 0.5rem; cursor: pointer;" class="slds-is-absolute slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-search slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right">  
        <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:add" size="xx-small" class="slds-icon-text-default" onclick={handleAdd} aria-hidden="true"></lightning-icon>
    </span> 
</div>
```

Here I created a new container with a relative positioning (`slds-is-relative`) which includes the `searchdiv` and the span with the icon. Then I setted an absolute positioning (`slds-is-absolute`) to the span element and provided some css. Finally an handler for onclick event has been attached to the lightning-icon.

An element with position `absolute` is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout. The element is positioned relative to its [closest containing block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block#identifying_the_containing_block), the first ancestor that has a `position` value other than `static`, and its final position is determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and left.
Keep in mind that if an element's position is not explicitly defined, then it's `static` by default. That's why I had to create a container with a relative positioning (using `slds-is-relative`) and I explicitly setted `top` and `right` values of the span element.
By the way, `z-index`, `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` have no effect on a `static` element.

[MDN - Positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning) reference.

Comment: Thank you for the code snippet and the explanation, sir.

Comment: Would you please give me some link on moving of the elements? I don't understand why making the icon element positioning absolute would also put it in the front of the input.

Comment: @dbase1 I updated the answer explaining the positioning and adding few links

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a 'lightning button icon'

`<lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:settings"  alternative-text="Settings" title="Settings" onclick={handleClick}></lightning-button-icon>`

Here the onclick handler will invoke your js code.

Here is a detailed documentation on it : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-button-icon/example